# How to make an Edittext with an underline for character for a fix size String in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I need to make a EditText that replace one underline for a char when the user adds new one. Something like this:

[image]

I make something similar, with 6 EditTexts (the size of the String needed) and a '_' char for the hint, a when writing in one a change the focus to the next and when deleting change the focus to the previuos, but I have problems when deleting or editing not the last char added.
 Anyone knows how can I to do it well?

This is my code in the activity:

```
   private void manageFocus(final EditText beforeET, final EditText currenteET, final EditText afterET) {

       if (beforeET != null) {
           currenteET.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                   if (hasFocus && beforeET != null && beforeET.getText().toString().length() < 1 && currenteET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                       beforeET.requestFocus();
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       currenteET.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
           @Override
           public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
           }

           @Override
           public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
               if (afterET != null && currenteET.getText().toString().length() >= 1) {
                   afterET.requestFocus();
               } else if (beforeET != null && currenteET.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                   beforeET.requestFocus();
               }
           }
       });
   }
```

And the layout code is this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/login_layout_code"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone">

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et02"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_code_et01"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et03"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_code_et02"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et04"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_code_et03"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et05"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_code_et04"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/login_code_et06"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="_"
android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray"
android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_32"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/login_code_et05"
android:inputType="number"
android:maxLength="1"
android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
fontPath="fonts/TitilliumText/TitilliumText22L-Bold.otf"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finaly, I found the solution only adding a TextWacher to the EditText and deletin one '*' to the next char when adding characters and adding a '*' when deleting to de position.

This is the xml code of the EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="______"
        android:letterSpacing="0.2"
        android:textSize="29sp" />
```

And this is the code in the activity:

```
    EditText editText;
    private String text;
    private boolean delete = false;
    private static final int CODE_SIZE=6;


  private void initTextView() {
        text = editText.getText().toString();

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                text = editText.getText().toString();
                if (count > after)
                    delete = true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                int replacePosition = editText.getSelectionEnd();

                if (s.length() != CODE_SIZE) {
                    if (!delete) {
                        if (replacePosition < s.length())
                            sb.deleteCharAt(replacePosition);
                    } else {
                        sb.insert(replacePosition, '_');
                    }

                        if (replacePosition < s.length() || delete) {
                            editText.setText(sb.toString());
                            editText.setSelection(replacePosition);
                        } else {
                            editText.setText(text);
                            editText.setSelection(replacePosition - 1);
                        }
                    }


                }

                delete = false;

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });


    }
```

This code works well in api level 21 and higher, because letterSpacin only work in API level 21 and higher. But if you use a different typography than Android stock it probably works. For me works with TitilliumText22L-Regular.

Answer (score 1):

I would try using a `TextView` behind the `EditText` (assuming your EditText has a transparent background) to show the underlines and update it whenever the text changes in the `EditText`.

Otherwise you could subclass `EditText` and implement some custom drawing in `onDraw()`.

Either of those I think would be better than having 6 `EditText`s and managing their focus with all that plumbing.

Comment: Thanks I thin in something like that, but if I delete a char in the midle of the EditText the line is will appear at the end of the EditText, no in the position deleted.

Comment: @JachumbelechaoUntoMantekilla Is that a requirement? I would argue that as a user, if i delete text in the middle, my expectation is the rest of the text  collapses to fill the space. That's how every other text field behaves, so why be different?

Comment: Yes is a requirement. If it were me I would do as you say.

Comment: Finally, I found a solution.